# What should be the type of variable?

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq.

My code is as below . I need to give the type for results variable. What it should be ?

I tried with assigning `results= Enumerable.Emoty<DataRow>();` and casting results to `DataRow` . But casting failed.

Can anyone tell this?

```
  var results; 

        if (rbtnSystemTypes.IsChecked == true)
        {
            results = (from DataRow dr in objDataTable.Rows
                       let Markets = dr.Field<bool>("IsActiveMarkets") == true ? "Active" : "Inactive"
                       let Budgets = dr.Field<bool>("IsActiveBudgets") == true ? "Active" : "Inactive"
                       let Programs = dr.Field<bool>("IsActivePrograms") == true ? "Active" : "Inactive"
                       select new
                       {
                           SlNo = objDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(dr) + 1,
                           Country = dr.Field<string>("SystemType"),
                           Market = dr.Field<string>("Market"),
                           ProgramType = dr.Field<string>("JDFType"),
                           Markets = Markets,
                           Budgets = Budgets,
                           Programs = Programs
                       });

        }
        else 
        {
            results = (from DataRow dr in objDataTable.Rows
                       let Markets = dr.Field<bool>("IsActiveMarkets") == true ? "Active" : "Inactive"
                       let Budgets = dr.Field<bool>("IsActiveBudgets") == true ? "Active" : "Inactive"
                       let Programs = dr.Field<bool>("IsActivePrograms") == true ? "Active" : "Inactive"
                       select new
                       {
                           SlNo = objDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(dr) + 1,
                           SubSystemType = dr.Field<string>("SubSystem"),
                           Market = dr.Field<string>("Market"),
                           SystemType = dr.Field<string>("SystemType"),
                           Markets = Markets,
                           Budgets = Budgets,
                           Programs = Programs
                       });
        }
```

Comment: Are you expecting a magical cast from an anonymous object to a DataRow? If so, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) in your `select` clauses - these have no specific name (hence anonymous).

Create a class to hold the results and use that as the type in your results.

```
public MarketData
{
  public int SlNo { get; set; }
  public string SubSystemType { get; set; }
  ...
}

// in the queries:
select new MarketData
{
  SlNo = objDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(dr) + 1,
  ...
}
```

Comment: And how does this fit into the `DataRow` requirement of the question?

Comment: @leppie - My reading of the question is that the OP _tried_ casting to `DataRow` as part of his failed attempts at casting to a known type, not that it is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dynamic` but wave goodbye to intellisense and compile time checking.

```
dynamic results;
```

The only time I do this is when I'm making quick and dirty linqpad queries and I don't want to go to the effort of creating a class for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is an anonymous type.

You can create a class that has the exact same fields and return that if you want.

or you could get the method to return a dynamic (you'll lose intellisense and compiler type checks).

Answer (score 0):

unless I'm missing something these are anonymous type

you cannot cast it, you need to create a custom class and do a

```
   select new MyNewClass()
                   {
                       SlNo
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be anonymous type, featured especially to LINQ.
IMHO - best practice is to return result.ToList().